# Cannot start node if snitch's data center (...) differs from previous data center (...)

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to start DSE 5.0.1 Cassandra (single node) on my local.

I'm getting the following error:

> CassandraDaemon.java:698 - Cannot start node if snitch's data center
> (Cassandra) differs from previous data center (Graph). Please fix the
> snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use
> the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true

Answer (score 12):

If you are using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch, start Cassandra with the option

```
-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true
```

If it starts successfully, execute:

```
nodetool repair
nodetool cleanup
```

Afterwards, Cassandra should be able to start normally without the ignore option.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_.

Comment: doesnt work. the cassandra service stops automatically.

Answer (score 8):

This occurs when the node starts and see's that it has information indicating that it was previously part of a different datacenter. This occurs if the datacenter was different on a prior boot and was then changed.

In your case you are most likely using `DseSimpleSnitch` which names the Datacenter based on the workload of that node. Previously the node was started with Graph enabled which turned the name to `Graph`. Now trying to start it without Graph enabled leads to it naming the Datacenter `Cassandra` which is the default.

Using the `-Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true` flag will allow you to proceed but a better solution would be to switch to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` and give this machine a dedicated datacenter name.

Another option (if you are just testing) is to wipe out the data directory as this will clear out the information previously labeling the datacenter for the node. This will most likely be `sudo rm -R /var/lib/cassandra/`

Answer (score 1):

This issue will happen when you change the datacenter name in the file `/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties`.

To resolve the issue, please follow these steps:

1. Clear the following directories (note: if you have data, please take a backup first by using the `cp` command to copy the files to a backup folder)

   ```
   cd /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

   sudo rm -rf *

   cd /var/lib/cassandra/data

   sudo rm -rf *
   ```
2. Now, start the DSE service with the following command:

   ```
   service dse start
   ```
3. Check the list node's status with this command:

   ```
   nodetool -h ::FFFF:127.0.0.1 status
   ```